# How to create frames from layers in Photoshop extended?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, animation, actions, adobe-bridge

Is there a way to automatically create frames from layers in a Photoshop document?

Bridge lets you open several images into one Photoshop document as layers, now I would like to get these layers loaded into the animation window (one frame per layer) without having to create frames one by one.

If you know of a better workflow in photoshop for putting together photos for a timelapse animation would also be helpful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is what I understood...

Yes there is a way, open up your animation panel.

I created some shapes and you can see how they were together in first SS, after clicking on the `make frames from the layer`, it automatically create all the layer as frames in animation panel.

Do according to my SS, is it what you needed? Sorry for these awful screenshots (open in new window for clarity) :|

Hope this will help....

[image: SS1]

[image: SS2]

[image: SS3]

Comment: Fantastic! What a great answer, even with screenshots. And very fast too. I wish I could vote it up more than once. Thank you.

Comment: your welcome deb :)

Comment: This solution is out of date. The other answer is now correct

Answer (score 5):

In Creative Cloud releases, this seems to have changed to a rather unintuitive process:

1. Get your layers ready to make frames from as usual.
2. Open the timeline panel by going to <kbd>Window</kbd> › <kbd>Timeline</kbd>.
3. You should see <kbd>Create Video Timeline</kbd> in the middle of the panel. Use the little arrow button next to it to switch it to <kbd>Create Frame Animation</kbd>, and then click it. This will create a single frame in the timeline.
4. Now you can open the panel options menu in the top right of the Timeline panel, where <kbd>Make Frames From Layers</kbd> will have become available. Click it, and voila!